# How to read from a socket, directly into a file

Tags: c++, c

In C (or C++) is there a way to receive data from a socket, but instead of reading it into a buffer in memory, it "receives" it into a file. I know that the usual way to do this is to receive the data into a char buffer, then write the buffer into a file.

Is there a function like sendfile(), which transports the data directly between files and sockets, but instead of sending data from a file to a socket, it receives data from the socket into a file?

Comment: @RetiredNinja For sendfile "The   in_fd   argument   must  correspond  to  a  file  which  supports mmap(2)-like operations (i.e., it cannot be a socket)."

Comment: In windows, there is TransmitFile function.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis `TransmitFile()` sends a file to a socket, not the other way around, which the OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to sendfile that works the other way around. But there is [splice()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) that transfers between 2 file descriptors, one of them must refer to a file.

So what you can do is socket -> pipe, pipe -> file. Whether that is still a gain over a buffer you have to measure. Splice is limited by the pipe buffer size while a read/write can work in arbitrary units reducing the number of syscalls.

Comment: Wouldn't this include all the control data in the socket as well?  My understanding is that `read` and `readfrom` strip that stuff out so you only get the actual data.

Comment: As will splice. I assume this is a TCP socket (SOCK_STREAM). I have no idea what a datagram socket would do with splice.

Comment: There's a Vanilla Ice joke in that last comment, but I think I'd have to work too hard to pull it out.

Comment: The OP didn't mention (nor tag) any specific OS. It might be worth to point out that `splice()` is a Linux specific solution. (Or, is something comparable available on other OSes also?)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat sendfile is a unix thing so I assume Linux. Other unixes are far less likely.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow That's clear for the Pro (like you) but not for the dummies (like me). I still believe either OP or you could have mentioned this for the common people... ;-)